# Running non-executable in Raspbian OS for Raspberry Pi in menu, can't find terminal

Tags: raspbian, terminal, pi-apps

I have installed Fern wifi cracker, it's a python file called "execute.py", I opened the "Main Menu Editor" app, that lets you add apps in the menu bar on the top of the screen. I selected the "New item" button and filled out the box like this:

```
Name:     fern
Command:  python3 /path/to/script/execute.py
Comment:  N/A
```

And I put the "Launch in terminal?" box checked.

I then tested it by opening that icon/file in the menu on the desktop and I get this error.

[image]

From [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ttfaTH6h0RM) 2 y/o video I found, what I am doing *should* work, but it doesn't.

I do recall messing around in the settings where I set my default launch terminal as something else, but it's a vague memory.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

Just add "x-terminal-emulator -e " then your command and it'll open a terminal  and run the command.

```
Name:     fern
Command:  x-terminal-emulator -e python3 /path/to/script/execute.py
Comment:  N/A
```